# Issue with custom validation rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js plugin. I have created a custom validation rule named `select` for selectlist. I have created a jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/fQBxM/1/

My problem is when i load the page, the validation message is already shown, but i want to show it only when user submit the form. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a default value `'0'` to your observable, then the validation won't fire for the initial value:

```
ko.observable('0').extend({ select: { message : "please select gender" } })
```

Demo [`JSfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/KDTB2/).